# Find shortest line in file C

Tags: c

So far I managed to get the longest line in a file like this:

```
int LongestLine(FILE *filename) {

  char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

  char line_val[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
  int line_len = -1;
  int line_num = -1;
  int cur_line = 1;

  filename = fopen(filename, "r");

  while(fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filename) != NULL) {
    int len_tmp = strlen(buf) - 1;

    if(buf[len_tmp] == '\n')
      buf[len_tmp] = '\0';

    if(line_len < len_tmp) {
      strncpy(line_val, buf, len_tmp + 1);
      line_len = len_tmp;
      line_num = cur_line;
    }

    cur_line++;
  }

  return line_num;
}
```

However, finding the shortest is gonna be slightly different using this logic. I can't just write: `if(line_len > len_tmp)`. How can I apply the same logic but for finding the shortest line in a file? Even a pseudo-code would do.

Comment: Puzzle: Shortest line length is `0` or `1`?

Comment: I'd say it ought be `1` since `0` would mean an empty line even though I've got rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
int line_len = MAX_LINE_LEN+1;
```

At the start to make sure the first line you read is shorter than the 'stored' shortest line-length.

```
int LongestLine(FILE *filename) {

  char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

  char line_val[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
  int line_len = MAX_LINE_LEN+1; //Set initial shortest line to big number.
  int line_num = -1;
  int cur_line = 1;

  filename = fopen(filename, "r");

  while(fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filename) != NULL) {
    int len_tmp = strlen(buf); 

    if(len_tmp>0 && buf[len_tmp-1] == '\n') {
      buf[len_tmp-1] = '\0';
      --len_tmp;
    }

    if(len_tmp >0 && line_len > len_tmp) {  //On first pass that encounters a non-empty line this will always trigger because of the read limit in fgets.
      strncpy(line_val, buf, len_tmp + 1);
      line_len = len_tmp;
      line_num = cur_line;
    }

    cur_line++;
  }

  return line_num;
}
```

Consider how the wider program should handle an entirely empty file or file of all blank lines.
that code will return `MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1` in such a condition. That may or may not suit your purpose.

Also it's not clear why your taking a copy of the shortest line and its line number.
You do nothing with them and don't return them from the function.
What good do the following lines do?

```
      strncpy(line_val, buf, len_tmp + 1);

      line_num = cur_line;
```

Comment: Could you please supply a PoC? I can't seem to find the notion behind it.

Comment: @schmitsz: Edited as requested.

Comment: I haven't declared `MAX_LINE_LEN`. Should it be `0` by default?

Comment: @schmitsz: Someone has declared it. You use it your program! It's passed to `fgets(.)` and so `MAX_LINE_LEN+1` will be longer than any line you read. In fact `MAX_LINE_LEN` will do because the null terminator on the string doesn't count to its length. It should a 'big' number exceeding the longest possible input line length.

Comment: Well the above returns the first blank line encountered. And I need a line which is at least 1 character long.

Comment: I didn't realise. I'll fix that. Unless a line full of spaces is a 'blank' line to you.

Comment: The version should now work for you. Also you need to handle the file ending without a newline and the last line of the file being entirely empty. I've put those traps in too.

Comment: Like the `len_tmp>0` check in `if(len_tmp>0 && buf[len_tmp-1] == '\n')`.

Comment: @chux: I believe that condition is actually redundant because `fgets()` will return `NULL` if nothing is read. However just on principle it's a good idea to range check.

Comment: The check is not redundant. `fgets()`, with exceptional data, can return not-`NULL` and have `buf` that begins with `'\0'`.  `fgets()` does not read a string.  It reads a line: `char` until encountering `'\n'`.  So the input _could_ be "\0jkl\n".  Not typical, but certainly a hacker exploit for code not well protected like yours.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I think I've misinterpreted the documentation and not realized those exceptional cases. I fix bugs I don't even know I have! I suppose that's why it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make the condition like this.

```
if( line_num==-1)
    line_len=len_tmp;
else if ( len_tmp < line_len){
     line_num=len_tmp;
    // do the code for getting that line.}
```

Comment: What should `line_tmp` be?